# I encountered a problem while doing this example from the book 'Beginning Node.JS'. The aim is to setting up requireJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

My File Structure -

```
> client-
>    -app.js
> index.html
> require.js
> server.js
```

server.js - to create a basic http server

````
const   http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

function send404(response) {
    response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write('Error 404: Resource not found.');
    response.end();
}

const server = http.createServer( (req,res) => {
    if(req.method == 'GET' && req.url == '/') 
    {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res);
    }
    else
    {
        send404(res);
    }
}).listen(3000);
console.log('server running on port 3000');```
````

index.html

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Hello There</title>
  <script 
      src="require.js"
      data-main="client/app.js">
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>Press Ctrl + Shift + J (windows) or CMD + Opt + J (MacOSX) to open up the console.</p>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
````

app.js

```
console.log('Hello RequireJS!');
```

I am supposed to get `Hello RequireJS!` as output in the chrome developer tools console.
But, i get 3 errors as shown below:

1.

> Denying load of
>   chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/app.js. Resources
>   must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order
>   to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

2.

> GET http://localhost:3000/require.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

3.

> GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

Please tell me if you have also encountered this problem and how to solve this.
Thanks.

`

Comment: why are two errors related to chorme extension? You never mentioned one. As for error #2, your "server" sends 404 for a request of anything but `/` .... so, `/require.js` will of course fail with 404 ... your problem is the server code doesn't any URI except `/`

Comment: I don't know why i am getting extension related errors.

Comment: My server is sending 404 because it can't find require.js. But, i have require.js exactly where it should be. Why server can't find require.js?

Comment: no, your server is sending 404 because a request for `/require.js` does not meet the criteria for the if condition ... `if(req.method == 'GET' && req.url == '/')` .... the ONLY time you will get a non 404 response is on a request for `/`

Comment: I think you should watch a youtube video or an online tutorial on how to do this